# Angular click event of child element inside focus event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, angular, model-view-controller

Html

```
 <div class="right-inner-addon">
     <i  (click)="toggleSelection()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
     <input (focus)="focusInFunction()" (focusout)="focusOutFunction()" class="form-control" />
 </div>
```

TypeScript

```
    toggleSelection() {
     //performing some operation    
    }

    focusInFunction() {      ;
      this.showText = 'true';
    }

    focusOutFunction() {
      this.showText  = 'false';
    }
```

Here the focus function is working correctly. But whenever I click on the glyphicon, it is not going to toggleSelection() event instead focusInFunction() method is calling.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Check if the glyphicon takes the required width and height and you are clicking at the right spot.

Comment: feel free to add a plunker in you question to shows us the issue.